# Abap Syntax error in Production only but not dev/qa

Tags: abap

I have recently come across a syntax error 'No type can be derived from the context for the operator 'VALUE'  in production that did not happen in dev or QA.

1. Declare a standard table type gty_t_type (of char20) in my class.
2. Create method A with importing parameter iv_param type gty_t_type.
3. Call class=>method A( exporting iv_param = value #( ( 'xxx' ) ( 'zzz' ) ).

The code compiled fine in dev and imported it to QA without errors. But failed to import to production with a syntax error. What might have caused the difference and lead to an error?

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to say anything without seeing the code/the transport requests, but maybe another transport is missing from production, i. e. transports were not imported in the proper order?

Comment: All code were in that one transport. No depency on other transports.

Comment: Maybe a different kernel version is used on the production system. You can check the kernel version by selecting the menu item System -> Status and then pressing Shift+F5. The ABAP compiler is part of the kernel and different kernel versions can lead to a different behavior.

Comment: It is indeed different. Prod is on a lower kernel version than the rest. That seems to be the only plausible explanation for now...

Comment: Beside the kernel function, it could be also missing extensions.

Comment: Thomas is right. Wouldnt be the first time I have seen different kernel versions in DEV and PRD.  That kind of syntax difference is DEV on 7.5 and prd  on 7.x lower . See Sm51 release info button